# VB.NET Decimal.Try parse for dot and comma values

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to parse string to decimal in vb.net which could contain dot or comma, for ex. '5000.00', '5000,00' (actually for Belgium and Niederlands).
Code for decimal with dot:

```
Decimal.TryParse(amountStr, amountVal)
```

Code for decimal with comma:

```
Decimal.TryParse(amountStr, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE"), amountVal)
```

Is it possible to combine these into one code without replacing comma in string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to combine these into one code without replacing comma in string?

String-replacement is the "usual" solution to this problem. A slightly more elegant alternative would be to check if the string contains a `.` or a `,` and then provide the "correct" CultureInfo to TryParse:

```
Dim isBelgianFormat As Boolean = amountStr.Contains(",")

Dim ci As CultureInfo = If(isBelgianFormat,
                           CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("nl-BE"),
                           CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

...Decimal.TryParse(amountStr, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, ci, amountVal)...
```

This will also allow you to "fine-tune" your guessing logic by replacing the first line with a more complicated algorithm. (For example, this "simple" solution will fail if your users use thousands separators, i.e., if you want to correctly "guess" the value of both `500.000,00` and `500,000.00`.)

That having been said, you *can* make your code more complicated to cover these cases as well, but how do you want to treat, for example, `500.000` or `500,000`? Is it half a million or 500?

Thus, **I urge you to reconsider your requirements**. Especially when parsing monetary values, *failing* with a helpful error message is often preferable to *guessing* what the user might have meant.